# How to scrape the categories belonging to the datasets with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I webscraped a site which has an url such as this: https://takipcimerkezi.net/services

I tried to get every information of the table except "aciklama"

This is my code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url='https://takipcimerkezi.net/services'
page= requests.get(url)
table=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

max_sipariş= table.find_all(attrs={"data-label":"Maksimum Sipariş"})
maxsiparis=[]
for i in max_sipariş:
    value=i.text
    
    maxsiparis.append(value)
min_sipariş= table.find_all(attrs={"data-label":"Minimum Sipariş"})
minsiparis=[]
for i in min_sipariş:
    value=i.text
    
minsiparis.append(value)
bin_adet_fiyati= table.find_all(attrs={"data-label":"1000 adet fiyatı "})
binadetfiyat=[]
for i in bin_adet_fiyati:
    value=i.text.strip()
    binadetfiyat.append(value)

id= table.find_all(attrs={"data-label":"ID"})
idlist=[]
for i in id:
    value=i.text
    idlist.append(value)

servis= table.find_all(attrs={"data-label":"Servis"})
servislist=[]
for i in servis:
    value=i.text
    servislist.append(value)
```

Then i took the values and put them into a excel sheet like this:
[image]

But, the last thing i need is, i need to add a new column for which category a row is in.

Eg: Row with the `id:"158"` is in the `"Önerilen Servisler"` category. Likewise `id:"4","1526","1","1494"...` and so on until `id:"1537"` this row need to be in `" Instagram %100 Gerçek Premium Servisler"` category.

I hope i explained the problem well how can i do such job ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add parent category column to the dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://takipcimerkezi.net/services"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for tr in soup.select("tr:not(:has(td[colspan], th))"):
    prev = tr.find_previous("td", attrs={"colspan": True})
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select("td")]
    all_data.append([prev.get_text(strip=True), *tds[:5]])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_data,
    columns=["Parent", "ID", "Servis", "1000 adet fiyatı", "Minimum Sipariş", "Maksimum Sipariş"],
)
print(df.head())
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
               Parent    ID                                                                                                              Servis 1000 adet fiyatı Minimum Sipariş Maksimum Sipariş
0  Önerilen Servisler   158      3613- Instagram Garantili Takipçi | Max 3M | Ömür Boyu Garantili | Düşüş Çok Az | Anlık Başlar | Günde 150K          13.17 TL             100          3000000
1  Önerilen Servisler     4  1495- Instagram Garantili Takipçi | Max 1M | 365 Gün Telafi Garantili | Hızlı Başlar | 30 Gün Telafi Butonu Aktif         12.07 TL              50          5000000
2  Önerilen Servisler  1526            4513- Instagram Takipçi | Max 500K | Yabancı Gerçek Kullanıcılar | Düşme Az | Anlık Başlar | Günde 250K         22.28 TL           10000           500000
3  Önerilen Servisler     1            3033- Instagram Türk Takipçi | Max 25K | %90 Türk  | İptal Butonu Aktif | Anlık Başlar | Saatte 1K-2K         21.49 TL              10            25000
4  Önerilen Servisler  1494         991- Instagram Çekilişle Takipçi | %100 Organik Türk  | Max 10K | Günlük İşleme Alınır | Günde 5K Atar !         37.50 TL            1000            10000
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

---

EDIT: Little bit explanation of code above:

- First I select all data row (rows that don't contain table header or cells with `colspan=` attribute (the data in this row will become our "Parent" column). This is done with CSS selector `"tr:not(:has(td[colspan], th))"`
- When iterating over these data rows, I need to know what is the "Parent". For this I use `tr.find_previous("td", attrs={"colspan": True})` which will select `<td>` with the `colspan=` attribute.
- I get all text from the `<td>` tags in this row and store it inside `all_data` list
- From this list I create a pandas DataFrame

Comment: for tr in soup.select("tr:not(:has(td[colspan], th))"):      can you explain this code's logic please ?

Comment: @luthierz This is CSS selector. `"tr:not(:has(td[colspan], th))"` means I want to select all `<tr>` tags which don't contain `<td>` with `colspan=` attribute or `<th>` tag

Comment: I got it. but i don't get why you need it? Can you explain your code a little please in general thanks a lot

Comment: @luthierz I've added a short explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply adapt the approach from [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75636215/14460824) and scrape the categories first to map them while scraping the data:

```
categories = dict((e.get('data-filter-category-id'),e.get('data-filter-category-name')) for e in soup.select('.dropdown-menu a[data-filter-category-name]'))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url='https://takipcimerkezi.net/services'

soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(
            url,
            cookies={'user_currency':'27d210f1c3ff7fe5d18b5b41f9b8bb351dd29922d175e2a144af68924e3064d1a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A13%3A%22user_currency%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A3%3A%22EUR%22%3B%7D;'}
        ).text
       )

categories = dict((e.get('data-filter-category-id'),e.get('data-filter-category-name')) for e in soup.select('.dropdown-menu a[data-filter-category-name]'))

data =  []

for e in soup.select('#service-tbody tr:has([data-label="Minimum Sipariş"])'):
    d = dict(zip(e.find_previous('thead').stripped_strings,e.stripped_strings))
    d['category'] = categories[e.get('data-filter-table-category-id')] if e.get('data-filter-table-category-id') else None
    data.append(d)
 
pd.DataFrame(data)[['ID',  'category', 'Servis', '1000 adet fiyatı', 'Minimum Sipariş','Maksimum Sipariş']]
```

##### Output

|  | ID | category | Servis | 1000 adet fiyatı | Minimum Sipariş | Maksimum Sipariş |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 158 | Önerilen Servisler | 3613- Instagram Garantili Takipçi | Max 3M | Ömür Boyu Garantili | Düşüş Çok Az | Anlık Başlar| Günde 150K | ≈ 0.6573 € | 100 | 3000000 |
| 1 | 4 | Önerilen Servisler | 1495- Instagram Garantili Takipçi | Max 1M | 365 Gün Telafi Garantili | Hızlı Başlar | 30 Gün Telafi Butonu Aktif | ≈ 0.6024 € | 50 | 5000000 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1326 | 1039 | Spotify Türk Dinlenme | 1833-⬆️ Spotify Premium Türk Dinlenme | 5K Tek Paket | Normal | ≈ 4.9778 € | 5000 | 5000 |
| 1327 | 1040 | Spotify Türk Dinlenme | 1834-⬆️ Spotify Premium Türk Dinlenme | 10K Tek Paket | Normal | ≈ 4.9778 € | 10000 | 10000 |

Comment: can i ask you something about this code

Comment: Sure, if it explicitly refers to and is in scope of OP - Else, simply [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75686450/how-to-scrape-the-categories-and-description-belonging-to-the-datasets-with-beau

Comment: can i ask you if you see and dowvoted my question if so why i want to know what did i do wrong thanks

Comment: You can, but I didn't look at your question yesterday and I didn't vote, but the points @Übermensch makes are quite coherent and include what I've already advised you about your first post. The clearer and more focused your question is, the higher the chance of good answers - by the way, take the votes as an incentive for improvement, that definitely helped me in the beginning and I take a lot. May check following links again:  [ask] / [mcve]